# JavaScript call stored procedure

Tags: javascript, mysql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

Trying to call a stored procedure from JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--#include file="Connections/sms.asp" -->

var UpdateCalls = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
UpdateCalls.ActiveConnection = MM_sms_STRING;
UpdateCalls.CommandText = "CALL sms.UpdateCalls()";
UpdateCalls.CommandType = 4;
UpdateCalls.CommandTimeout = 0;
UpdateCalls.Prepared = true;
UpdateCalls.Execute();

</script>
```

I tested the stored procedure in MySQL and it executes correctly, but not from JavaScript.
The syntax seems to be correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");` is this JavaScript?

Comment: You forgot `runat="server"`. Try having: `<script language="JScript" runat="server">` and it should work fine. If still  no luck, post full error message and what line is causing it.

Comment: @Felix yes it's classic ASP written with JScript which is also called JavaScript for some reason. :/

Comment: If this is classic ASP then drop the asp.net tag

Comment: @Shadow Wizard -- that really looks like an answer :-)

Comment: @Shadow: [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jscript) is an implementation of the [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) language standardized by ECMA-262. [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jscript) is Microsoft's implementation.

Comment: @Sean too simple to be considered answer IMO.. anyway as it turned out it wasn't the case. :-)

Comment: @Matt thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

```
var UpdateCalls = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
UpdateCalls.ActiveConnection = MM_sms_STRING;
UpdateCalls.CommandText = "sms.UpdateCalls()";
UpdateCalls.CommandType = 4;
UpdateCalls.CommandTimeout = 0;
UpdateCalls.Prepared = true;
UpdateCalls.Execute();
```

there is no need to put the CALL in commandtext, just the sproc name.

Thanks everyone.